# Link Javascript file hosted on google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, script-tag

Researching how to accomplish this and my .js file is not working.

Here it is embedded:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://googledrive.com/host/id_goes_here/"></script>
```

I have already made the folder and the file public to everyone. Why is my html not recognizing this linked file?

Comment: Use your developer tools, especially the script console and the network panel. What errors do you get?

Comment: The error I'm seeing says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" and from my understanding I have linked it correctly.

Comment: Well, no, 404 means that the link is wrong (or it's hidden).

Comment: So, if I want to link the .js file, I would copy the id that is in the url when I open it in google drive. Then paste that id in the "id_goes_here" portion of the url that is embedded in the original question. Is that correct? Both the file and the folder that it is stored in is shared.

Comment: Google no longer supports hosting files in drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the most reputable documentation I can find (and wasting about an hour trying this myself unsuccessfully), Google Drive no longer supports hosting web files. That's why your `<script>` tag source will not work. This is stated in the following links:

> Google no longer allows hosting files from Google Drive. It is no
>   longer possible to serve javascript or css files from Google Drive.
>   This feature was shutdown on 1st September 2016...

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/blogger/HjOU0jIidQY/_k6FtwnVDwAJ
https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html

Comment: Great find on the documentation, unfortunately you're correct. I had to host my files elsewhere.