# How to host Third Party Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm a web developer and I want to use third party Javascript in my html file. I tried uploading it to google drive and then using the scr attribute of the script tag but it doesn't work. Please help.

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<script src = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1WU2AoUgwBxgH0yLoed9SQ71rP-JnBvgR" >

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript I uploaded:

```
console.log("Hello World");
```

So how can I make the Javascript Code (console.log("Hello World");) a Third Party Javascript? I don't have my own website domain though so please give some suggestions like Google or something that I can use to host my Third Party Javascript code. Thank you so much!

Edit:
Turns out I can't use Google for it. I've decided to use Github instead. Any ideas how to get started? (Like where do I go to upload the test.js file?) Thanks!!!

Comment: The issue doesn't seem to be with the HTML used.

Comment: "it doesn't work" - what does that mean? Did you check your browser's developer console to see whether the link properly returns a JS file or anything else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Link Javascript file hosted on google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39966504/link-javascript-file-hosted-on-google-drive) - Google does not support hosting files on Google drive.

Comment: Also, it does not sound like a good idea to use Google Drive for such files. Why not use a proper domain?

Comment: Google drive does not allow hosting web files, you can't just link any content with src. You can implement a drive client, download your script in an embedded script, parse it...etc. but in the end this does not worth the hassle.

Comment: Host it on github? Anyway, this is asking for advise on external resources ... seems off-topic here.

Comment: If you _have_ the script why not just store it in the same folder as the HTML? Why go through the bother of hosting it somewhere else?

Comment: @Andy because I want to keep it a clean, single html file

Comment: That makes no sense. Storing the JS file in the same folder keeps the HTML file clean